# How can I manipulate the Body of a Response with an ASP.NET Core Middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, middleware

I have the following `Invoke`-method in a middleware I'm playing with:

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-SW-Start", "GO");
    var stream = context.Response.Body;
    var buffer = new MemoryStream();
    context.Response.Body = buffer;
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-CanSeek", context.Response.Body.CanSeek.ToString());
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-CanRead", context.Response.Body.CanRead.ToString());
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-CanTimeout", context.Response.Body.CanTimeout.ToString());
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-CanWrite", context.Response.Body.CanWrite.ToString());
    await next.Invoke(context);
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-SW-Stoppp", $"FINISH {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");

    buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var bufferString = new StreamReader(buffer).ReadToEnd();
    bufferString = bufferString.Replace("[[[", "***");
    var newBuffer = GenerateStreamFromString(bufferString);
    await newBuffer.CopyToAsync(stream);
    await stream.FlushAsync();
    //context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    //var swr = new StreamWriter(buffer);

    //swr.WriteLine("<!-- bob -->");
    //await swr.FlushAsync();
}
```

Ignore all the response headers, writeline-debugging ftw...

This actually works, once, then all subsequent requests are empty except for the headers. All I really want to do is go to the top of the response-pipeline, and then run some global string-replace on the entire document body before it's sent to the browser. If anyone has any better way to do this then by all means...